# How to prove intersection compact problem?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

If A and B are compact set, then A∩B is compact set.

How to prove this problem?.

I know compact, but not use to this problem...

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$? Are they subsets of the Euclidean space?

Comment: It's false in general, so what's the context?